# installed apps name verus search name

Tags: c#

I will be straight forward and say that I found this code online and therefore is not my own.  It works perfectly if I type in the name of the program as shown in Programs and Features but for instance, I want to type Mozilla Firefox and have it find the installed Mozilla Firefox 26.0 (x86 en-US).  I tried many times to use .substring and .contains in the line that checks the two strings but each time leads the program to just lock up.  Any help is appreciated.

Just for side notes:
I am using a list of programs in a txt file that are read in to check against the installed apps.
I ran a messagebox right after it sets the display name and several of the message boxes show up blank.  I tried to limit it with string.length not being 0 and length being equal or greater than the string from the txt file but all still locks up the program.

Code:

```
private static bool IsAppInstalled(string p_machineName, string p_name)
{
    string keyName;

    // search in: CurrentUser
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInRemoteSubKey(p_machineName, RegistryHive.CurrentUser, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // search in: LocalMachine_32
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInRemoteSubKey(p_machineName, RegistryHive.LocalMachine, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // search in: LocalMachine_64
    keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    if (ExistsInRemoteSubKey(p_machineName, RegistryHive.LocalMachine, keyName, "DisplayName", p_name) == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
private static bool ExistsInRemoteSubKey(string p_machineName, RegistryHive p_hive, string p_subKeyName, string p_attributeName, string p_name)
{
    RegistryKey subkey;
    string displayName;

    using (RegistryKey regHive = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(p_hive, p_machineName))
    {
        using (RegistryKey regKey = regHive.OpenSubKey(p_subKeyName))
        {
            if (regKey != null)
            {
                foreach (string kn in regKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    using (subkey = regKey.OpenSubKey(kn))
                    {
                        displayName = subkey.GetValue(p_attributeName) as string;
                        MessageBox.Show(displayName);
                        if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true) // key found!
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried too many different things to list (or remember)... If it helps this is the majority of the rest of the code calling it:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = new string[250];
    string msg = "";
    string path = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
    if (blah.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader filePick = new StreamReader(@path + "\\blah.txt");
            int counter = 0;
            while ((lines[counter] = filePick.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            filePick.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg += ex.Message;
        }
    }
    else if (blah2.Checked)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader filePick = new StreamReader(@path + "\\blah2.txt");
            int counter = 0;
            while ((lines[counter] = filePick.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            filePick.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg += ex.Message;
        }
    }

    string MACHINE_NAME = System.Environment.MachineName;
    int counter2 = 0;
    string APPLICATION_NAME = "";
    string filename = "";
    while (lines[counter2] != null)
    {
        APPLICATION_NAME = lines[counter2];
        try
        {
            bool isAppInstalled = IsAppInstalled(MACHINE_NAME, APPLICATION_NAME);
            if (isAppInstalled == true)
            {
                appsNeedAttention = true;
                msg += APPLICATION_NAME + " is still installed.";
            }
            counter2++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg += ex.Message;
        }
    }

    if (blah.Checked == true)
    {
        filename = "blah.txt";
    }
    else if (blah2.Checked == true)
    {
        filename = "blah2.txt";
    }
    if (counter2 == 0 && File.Exists(filename) == true)
    {
        msg = "There are no programs listed in the file.";
    }
    if (msg != "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: It helps if you tell us your input, what the expected output is, the actual output, and the details of any exceptions that occurred.

Comment: the input is just a txt file with program names (each program name being on a separate line), the output is just a msgbox with saying which of the programs are actually installed.

Comment: and, despite didn't matched, did mozilla firefox shown in messagebox? if it wasn't shown then the problem is not in logic for matching, it is in logic for getting list of installed apps instead

Comment: yes with the msgbox.show after the displayname set the Mozilla Firefox 26.0 (x86 en-US) shows up perfectly in the msgbox.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what strings are being read from the operating system and what user input you want to match them with so that we can help you figure out how to do the string matching without having to slog through all of your other code.

Comment: ok, my apologies for the "slogging."  I am however headed out so I shall return tomorrow after work.

side note:

I changed the line to
if (p_name.Equals(displayName.Substring(0, p_name.Length-1), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true) // key found!

and the messagebox.show for displayname was not showing all the installed programs.
I shall do a minimal example tomorrow.

Comment: @Saposhiente actually the 1st snippet above is enough to reproduce the problem. simply put both method in console app -> change messagebox with console.writeline() -> call the method in Main() : `var result = IsAppInstalled("PC-Name", "firefox");`. But yeah, will be better if OP explained this in his post instead of Me.

Comment: @har07 Is what's up there right now complete and tested? Sure. Readable? Okay. Minimal? Quite the opposite.

Comment: @har07 Getting the list of installed software isn't the problem; he's doing that fine. It's matching this list to user input where the problem is; the minimal example of this problem is just example list of programs in, example user input in, matching out.

Comment: @Saposhiente ok, how far the problem should be reduced is opinion based. I found some cases where OP tried to post *minimal* code, reduced too much and ended up posting 2nd question providing his real code because he couldn't apply the solution in actual context.

Comment: @har07's answer to this was the key to solving my issue.  A big thank you goes to him and therefore I shall not be posting any minimal code of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this part :

```
if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
{
    return true;
}
```

To this :

```
//check null to avoid error
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
{
    //convert both string to lower case to ignore case difference
    //and use contains to match partially
    if (displayName.ToLower().Contains(p_name.ToLower()))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```